# How to empty the array value or unset the array value in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

This is my code:

```
 foreach ($category_attribute_list_value as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value_fial) {
            if($key==0){
                $x[]=$value_fial->attribute_value;
                $x_id[]=$value_fial->attribute_value_id;
            }
        }}
        foreach ($category_attribute_list_value as $key_y => $value_y) {
        foreach ($value_y as $key2_y => $value_fial_y) {
            if($key_y!=0)
                {
                $y[]=$value_fial_y->attribute_value;
                $y_id[]=$value_fial_y->attribute_value_id;
                }
        }}
```

In an above code $x contain two value (L,XL) and same for $y, it's have two value (Blue, Green).

Now came to table data code

My table code is:

```
echo'<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="pro_code_table">
<tr>
<td class="table_val_data">Code</td>';
foreach($x as $k_x => $v_x){
echo'<td class="table_val_data">'.$v_x.'</td>';
}
echo'</tr>';

foreach($y as $k_y_t=> $v_y_t){
echo'<tr><td class="table_val_data">'.$v_y_t.'</td>';
foreach($y as $k_y=> $v_y){
    foreach($x as $k_x => $v_x){
    $i=1;
    if($k_y_t==$k_y){
        echo'<td class="table_val_data">';
    //foreach($pro_code as $k_pro_code=> $v_pro_code){
    //if($k_x.'-'.$k_y==$k_pro_code){
        echo '<input type="text" name="edit_pro_code[]" value="'.$i.'"">';
    //}
    //}             
    echo'</td>';
    }    
    } 
    $i++;
}
echo'</tr>';
}
echo'</table>';
```

In an table code We split the data into X and y axises, X for an $x and y for an $y.

The whole table looped more the one time (assume it..!), in this cause only we have an error in looping

An first time looped data

The $y value is like this `Array ( [0] => bule [1] => green )` 
Next time looping i want the same data, but i have the below o/p

```
Array ( [0] => bule [1] => green [2] => L [3] => XL [4] => bule [5] => green )
```

How its merged automatically., Ref the below screen shot
[image]

Comment: The second time looping also i need same first loop o/p

Comment: The first time loop  the value of $y is Array ( [0] => bule [1] => green )

Comment: and then next time loop the same value of $y is like below Array ( [0] => bule [1] => green [2] => L [3] => XL [4] => bule [5] => green )

Comment: the value is automatically merged, how can i unset the remains values

Comment: @Anant i got the solution

Comment: i post my answer bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my answer is:

```
foreach ($category_attribute_list_value as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value_fial) {
        if($key==0)
        {
            $x[]=$value_fial->attribute_value;
            $x_id[]=$value_fial->attribute_value_id;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($category_attribute_list_value as $key_y => $value_y) {
    foreach ($value_y as $key2_y => $value_fial_y) {
        if($key_y==1)
        {
            $y_temp[]=$value_fial_y->attribute_value;
            $y_id[]=$value_fial_y->attribute_value_id;
        }
    }
}
            $y=array_unique($y_temp);

                //$x=array('L','XL');
                //$y=array('P','dsfs'); 
                //$x_id=array(1,2);
                //$y_id=array(5,6);
                //$xv=array_combine($x_id, $x);
                //$yv=array_combine($y_id, $y);

echo'<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="store_inven_table">
<tr>
<td class="table_val_data">Code</td>';
foreach($x as $k_x => $v_x){
echo'<td class="table_val_data">'.$v_x.'</td>';
}
echo'</tr>';

    foreach($y as $k_y_t=> $v_y_t){
    echo'<tr><td class="table_val_data">'.$v_y_t.'</td>';
    foreach($y as $k_y=> $v_y){
        foreach($x as $k_x => $v_x){
        if($k_y_t==$k_y){
            echo'<td class="store_val_data_input">';
            echo '<input type="text" name="store_pro_inv_qty[]" value="">
            <input type="text" value="'.$value_final_store->store_id.'" name="store_inventory_ids[]">';
        echo'</td>';
        }    
        } 
    }
    echo'</tr>';
    }

echo'</table>';
$x=array();$x_id=array();$y=array();$y_id=array();$value=array();
```

My o/p is like below:
[image]

Comment: Mark this answer for others help. +10 from my side to do it yourself.

Comment: it shows like that "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107711/discussion-between-karnagowtham-and-anant).